# HTML Shadow dom: why does attachShadow(...).insertAdjacentHTML not work but attachShadow(...).innerHTML work?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

Why do the following two work:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div>Test1</div>';

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<div>Test2</div>');
```

and this also works:

```
document.body.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = '<div>Test3</div>';
```

But following doesn't work:

```
document.body.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<div>Test4</div>');
```

It gives error `Uncaught TypeError: document.body.attachShadow(...).insertAdjacentHTML is not a function`

https://jsfiddle.net/uzdy3fv9/

Comment: A `ShadowRoot` object does not have an `insertAdjacentHTML` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div>Test1</div>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<div>Test2</div>');
```

you are invoking methods on `Element.prototype`.

Shadow roots aren't element - they're similar in some respects, but they're not the same. Shadow roots [have certain methods/properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot), including `.innerHTML`, but not including `.insertAdjacentHTML`.

(which makes sense... what would `.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend'` or `'beforebegin'` even mean with a shadow root? The shadow root is not part of a container)

Comment: The `afterend` and `beforebegin` part at the end makes sense. However, then how would one go about using the benefits of `insertAdjacentHTML` such as inserting at a specific position after a certain element within the shadow dom?

Comment: You could select one of the shadow root's children and then call `insertAdjacentHTML` on that element, instead of on the shadow root instead.

Comment: *you are invoking methods on `Element.prototype`*. `innerHTML`, while certainly realized with a setter function internally, technically it still is a *property* and not a method.

Comment: As so I understand, `insertAdjacentHTML` does work for elements inside the shadow dom, but just not on the root itself? That brings me back to the `what would afterend and beforebegin` even mean part. Those do work when executing against the `document.body`. They just place it outside the `</body>`. Couldn't the same have been done for shadow dom too?

Comment: @PranoyC The difference is that the `document.body` has a container - namely, the HTML document itself. In contrast, a shadow root does not have a container, so creating elements "adjacent" to it outside its container doesn't make sense. For the same reason, shadow roots don't have `outerHTML`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Would have just made sense if they allowed the other two except `afterend` and `beforebegin` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Shadow root API simply doesn't offer an `insertAdjacentHTML` method.

Please note that even `innerHTML` on shadow roots isn't part of the official standard.

See

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot

Comment: Since `innerHTML` and `insertAdjacentHTML` isn't part of official standard, would the only way to insert elements be using the old school `appendChild` way which involves the extra step of serialization?

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#the-innerhtml-mixin has `ShadowRoot includes InnerHTML;`, right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance *W3C Editor's Draft 20 April 2020* Drafts are not part of the official standard (yet).

Comment: *the old school appendChild way which involves the extra step of serialization* **that is not old school at all.** It's actually the preferred way to create elements for a whole bunch of reasons, safety against cross site scripting being only one aspect. If you insist to stick with unsafe properties and methods such as the two your questions asks, consider using trusted types along with a content security policy configured to enable trusted types.

Comment: The specification may not be stable, but it is nonetheless the de-facto "official current standard". W3C likes to have things written in stone, In contrast I personally prefer WHATWG's posture of having a Living Standard, but if you will, W3C's drafts are LS. The fact is that all browsers implementing the ShadowRoot interface are following this draft-spec. There is even [WPT tests](https://wpt.fyi/results/shadow-dom/innerHTML-setter.xhtml?label=master&label=experimental&aligned&q=innerhtml) for this.